# DataGridView not filtering with DataView

Tags: c#

I've populated a DataTable from a SQL query and it displays correctly when i load it into a DataGridView:

```
private DataTable = new DataTable("cases");
.
.
.
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("select * from cases"))
{
    var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, connection);
    var commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
    adapter.Fill(CasesDataTable);

    dataGridViewCases.DataSource = CasesDataTable;
}
```

Now I have a second DataGridView that I want to populate using the same data put with a filter on it:

```
DataView dataView = new DataView(CasesDataTable);
dataView.RowFilter = "status = 'Opened'";
dataGridViewOpenCases.DataSource = dataView;
```

However it just displays all data and not the filtered data. If I do sort:

```
dataView.Sort = "name ASC";
```

it sorts correctly. It seems the RowFilter for whatever reason isn't filtering.
I've looked around but can't find anything to suggest what is wrong.

Comment: Do all rows have status "Opened"?

Comment: Usually I copy datatable like this :             DataTable filterTable = CasesDataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("ID") == 123).CopyToDataTable();

Comment: no, there is a mixture of opened, closed, assigned, blank

Comment: does it work as expected with `"select * from cases where status = 'Opened'"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Turns out someone had added code that executed after mine which reloaded the data. So it was being loaded, filtered, and then reloaded.

Thanks for the help regardless.